# Adding data in an Assosiative Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

How come when i try to add something into the "Enfant" array that i have initialized it gives me a number. In this case it gives me 3 when i add a string into it.

```
    var person=[];

function addPerson(n,a){
    person.push({ "Name" : n, "Age" : a, "Kid" : []});

}
```

addPerson("Julie",100);
   addPerson("Sarah",83);

```
function addKid(parentName,kidName){

    for(var i=0;i<person.length;i++){
        if (parentName== person[i].Name){
            person[i].Kid=person.push(kidName);
    }   
  }
}

addKid("Julie","Sarah");
print(person[0].Kid); //<--- gives me 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `person[i].Kid.push` instead.

```
function addKid(parentName,kidName){

    for(var i=0;i<person.length;i++){
        if (parentName== person[i].Name){
            person[i].Kid.push(kidName);
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: thx. lets say i want to call the age of the parent of the kid. person[0].Kid[0].Age gives a blank. i have to re-push in the age?

Comment: @user3268216 yes, or you can change the line to `person[1].Kid.push({ "Name" : kidName, "Age" : kidAge, "Kid" : []});` and add `kidAge` to the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the number of elements in the array after the push, which is what you're assigning to `person[i].Kid`